# Select all table in 2 table with null value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I Have 2 Table in SQL SERVER 2005:

first table :

```
Tanggal
2015/01/01
2015/01/02
2015/01/03
2015/01/04
2015/01/05
2015/01/06
```

Second Table :

```
Tanggal               Jam_Masuk          Jam_Pulang.    Id_user
2015/01/01        08:00:00                17:00:00         00600320 
2015/01/03        08:00:00                17:00:00         00600320 
2015/01/05        08:00:00                17:00:00         00600320 
2015/01/06        08:00:00                17:00:00         00600320
```

I want select like this :

```
Tanggal               Jam_Masuk          Jam_Pulang           Total              Status      Id_user
2015/01/01        08:00:00                17:00:00               09:00:00        OK          00600320   
2015/01/02        --:--:--                --:--:--               --:--:--        ALPHA/IZIN  00600320 
2015/01/03        08:00:00                17:00:00               09:00:00        OK          00600320   
2015/01/04        --:--:--                --:-- :--              --:--:--        ALPHA/IZIN  00600320 
2015/01/05        08:00:00                17:00:00               09:00:00        OK          00600320   
2015/01/06        08:00:00                17:00:00               09:00:00        OK          00600320
```

Note : Field Total (hh:mm:ss)= Jam_Pulang - Jam_Masuk

Thanks Before

Comment: SQL Server 2005 has neither a `date` nor a`time` data type.  So please describe what the types of the columns are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` the two tables, Use a `CASE` statement for the Status and use the `DATEDIFF` function for the total. Also use `CONVERT` for the datestamp `Tanggal` with style `111` for your expected output of `YYYY/MM/DD`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),a.Tanggal,111) AS Tanggal, 
b.Jam_Masuk, 
b.Jam_Pulang, 
DATEDIFF(hour, Jam_Masuk, Jam_Pulang) AS Total,
b.Id_user, 
CASE WHEN b.Id_user IS NOT NULL THEN 'OK' ELSE NULL END AS Status
FROM tab1 a
LEFT JOIN tab12 b ON a.Tanggal = b.Tanggal
```

OUTPUT

```
Tanggal     Jam_Masuk   Jam_Pulang  Total   Id_user Status
2015/01/01  08:00:00    17:00:00    9       600320  OK
2015/01/02  (null)      (null)      (null)  (null)  (null)
2015/01/03  08:00:00    17:00:00    9       600320  OK
2015/01/04  (null)      (null)      (null)  (null)  (null)
2015/01/05  08:00:00    17:00:00    9       600320  OK
2015/01/06  08:00:00    17:00:00    9       600320  OK
```

Comment: it work. nice
but if i want in id_user not null. i use this query :

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),a.Tanggal,111) AS Tanggal, 
b.Jam_Masuk, 
b.Jam_Pulang, 
DATEDIFF(hour, Jam_Masuk, Jam_Pulang) AS Total,
b.Id_user, 
CASE WHEN b.Id_user IS NOT NULL THEN 'OK' ELSE NULL END AS Status
FROM tab1 a
LEFT JOIN tab12 b ON a.Tanggal = b.Tanggal
where id_user = '00600320'


why in date 2015/01/02 and 04 not include.
Thank's